# TCP/IP connection on VxWorks

Tags: tcp, vxworks

*Hi everyone*
Well i am trying to perform a simple TCP/IP connection and send 3 doubles to a remote host. I am working on VxWorks on a MRI scanner.

I am using socket.h to initialize sockets BUT  netinet/in.h is missing (specific to this custom environement of programmation, i think). 
This is really annoying because sockaddr_in is in netinet/in.h .

The thing is that in connect function, sockaddr_in is recasted in sockaddr  ( socket.h)

My question is then : is it possible to initialize an IP adress only with sockaddr

```
int sockfd, portno, n;

struct sockaddr_in serv_addr;

sockfd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);

 if (connect(sockfd,(struct sockaddr *) &serv_addr,sizeof(serv_addr)) < 0) 

 int buffer=0;
 n = write(sockfd,buffer,strlen(buffer));

close(sockfd);
```

Thank you very much for your help,
Pierre

Answer (score 0):

Yes,  sockaddr and sockaddr_in are interchangeable. You can use one or the other. They both contain 16 bytes. In your code you can define:
struct sockaddr serv_addr;
It will be the same.